# no entrypoint was specified in job specification. Either add an entrypoint in the job spec or provide it with the --entry flag

Tags: toit

I'm trying to deploy my very first Toit code to my device. I'm following the only tutorial I can find on Toit and servos and when it comes time to deploy using the TOIT CLI I get the following error message:

> no entrypoint was specified in job specification. Either add an entrypoint in the job spec or provide it with the --entry flag.

I have a feeling that something might not be lining up in naming between my .toit file and the .yaml file. I thought I checked all the boxes but have been frustrated at every turn. Can you identify with this error? Here's the command I'm being told to use(with the two substitutions being made):
$toit deploy -d rough-hall coop-door.yaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [app specification](https://docs.toit.io/platform/apps/appspec) tells the Toit framework how to run a Toit program.

For that it needs at least two things:

- the name
- which Toit file to run

The second one is called "entrypoint" in the yaml file.

A simple app yaml file could look like the following:

```
name: simple_app
entrypoint: my_app.toit
```

#### More specifically to your question

I'm assuming you are referring to the [this chicken-coop tutorial](https://opencloudware.com/building-toit-servo-door-for-an-iot-based-automated-chicken-coop-door-with-esp32/).

The code in some of the examples got mangled a bit (like the last line of the cron job not being intended). Maybe that's the reason there is an error.

Try to use the code directly from the github repository: https://github.com/Open-Cloudware/toit-servo-coop-door/blob/main/servo_door_day.yaml

I cloned that repository and then ran

```
toit pkg install
toit deploy servo_door_day.yaml
```

and that installed the application on my device.